# how to make the session lifetime counted from the start of the page load, checked every minute and not disrupted by post request?

Tags: javascript, django

session life settings SESSION_COOKIE_AGE=120 (2 minutes)
now a question, at the first rendering of the page of the template confirm_email.html the form of code input from 6 fields is loaded, if you do not enter the code (inactivity) and wait, then every minute will be checked to send a get request from the script check_session.js every minute in the view CheckSession and it will give json response back and 30 seconds before the end of session life will trigger the script timer.js and after the end of 2 minutes the user will be redirected to the main page - everything is fine here!!!!.
And if at the first rendering of the confirm_email.html template page (for example, the page loaded at 18:00:00) the form of code input from 6 fields is loaded, and suppose you enter an incorrect code after 30 seconds (at 18:00:30), then a post request is sent to the ConfirmEmail view and the check_session script. js will send a request to the CheckSession view from this post request time, i.e. the script will send a request at 18:01:30, i.e. a minute from the post request, but not from the time the page loaded at 18:00:00.

Where it is necessary and how to fix the code, so that at the initial loading of the page confirm_email. html with a modal window for entering a code of 6 fields, a get request is sent every minute from the start of loading this page (i.e. the form of the modal window) and if the post request is executed, the form page will be refreshed, then the get request will not be sent from the time of the post request (now with this code it happens exactly like this, after entering an incorrect code of 6 digits the post request of the ConfirmEmail view will be executed and then from this time the get request will be executed via fetch on check_session/ in a minute - and this is wrong).

views.py ConfirmEmail:

```
class ConfirmEmail(SuccessMessageMixin,View):
    template_name = 'mos_sel/confirm_email.html'
    success_message='Пользователь %(username)s был успешно создан.\nЗалогиньтесь, чтобы продолжить'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = EmailConfirmationForm()
        user_email = request.session.get('email','')
        username = request.session.get('username', user_email.split('@')[0])
        anonymized_email = request.session.get('anonymized_email', '')
        if not user_email:  # Если сессия истекла
            User = get_user_model()
            user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)
            user.delete()  # Удалить пользователя
            # Удаляем email_confirmed из сессии и обновляем сессию
            del request.session['email']
            request.session.modified = True
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('Login'))  # Перенаправить на главную страницу
        request.session['email_confirmed'] = False
        request.session['last_activity'] = tz.now().isoformat()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'user_email': user_email, 'username': username, 'show_modal': True,'session_timeout': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE,})  

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_email = request.session.get('email', '')
        print(f'сессия email_confirmed вначале post {request.session["email_confirmed"]}')
        if not user_email:  # Если сессия истекла
            User = get_user_model()
            user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)
            user.delete()  # Удалить пользователя
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('Login'))  # Перенаправить на главную страницу
        form = EmailConfirmationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.session.get('username', user_email.split('@')[0])
        anonymized_email = request.session.get('anonymized_email', '')
        if form.is_valid():
            code = form.cleaned_data['code1'] + form.cleaned_data['code2'] + form.cleaned_data['code3'] + form.cleaned_data['code4'] + form.cleaned_data['code5'] + form.cleaned_data['code6']
            User = get_user_model()
            user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)
            email_confirmation = EmailConfirmation.objects.filter(
                code=code,
                user=user
                ).first()
            if email_confirmation:
                email_confirmation.delete()
                user.is_active = True
                user.email_confirmed = True  # Устанавливаем email_confirmed в True
                request.session['email_confirmed'] = True
                user.save()
                success_message = self.success_message % dict(username=username,)
                messages.success(request, success_message)
                return redirect(reverse_lazy('SuccessMessage'))
               
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Неправильный код. Попробуйте снова.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Код введен неверно.')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'user_email': user_email, 'username': username, 'show_modal': True,'session_timeout': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE,})
```

template confirm_email.html

```
<body id='custom_background_image' data-session-timeout="{{ session_timeout }}" data-last-activity="{{ request.session.last_activity }}" data-url="{% url 'check_session' %}">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Задний фон -->
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <!-- Модальное окно -->
    <div class="modal fade {% if show_modal %}show d-block{% endif %}" id="confirmEmailModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="confirmEmailModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered mx-auto my-custom-modal">
            <div class="modal-content " id="modal_background_color">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="confirmEmailModalLabel"><strong>Завершение регистрации </strong></h5>
                    <button type="button" id="close_registr_modal" data-url="{% url 'Home' %}" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="insert_timer"></div>
                    {% if messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Ошибка подтверждения:</strong><br>
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            {{ message }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <p> <strong> Введите код подтверждения </strong></p>
                    
                    <p>  Приветствуем Вас, <strong> {{ username }}</strong>!</p>
                    <div class="text mb-4">Мы отправили 6-значный код на <strong>{{ user_email }}</strong>
                    Подтвердите, что номер принадлежит вам, чтобы обезопасить свою учетную запись
                    </div>
                    <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-between">
                            <div class="col"><input type="text" name="code1" maxlength="1" class="form-control digit-input" id="code1"></div>
                            <div class="col"><input type="text" name="code2" maxlength="1" class="form-control digit-input" id="code2"></div>
                            <div class="col"><input type="text" name="code3" maxlength="1" class="form-control digit-input" id="code3"></div>
                            <div class="col"><input type="text" name="code4" maxlength="1" class="form-control digit-input" id="code4"></div>
                            <div class="col"><input type="text" name="code5" maxlength="1" class="form-control digit-input" id="code5"></div>
                            <div class="col"><input type="text" name="code6" maxlength="1" class="form-control digit-input" id="code6"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-2 mb-1">
                            <button type="submit" id="confirm_code" class="btn btn-primary">Подтвердить</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

views.py CheckSession:

```
class CheckSession(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Проверка времени последней активности
        last_activity_str = request.session.get('last_activity', None)
        if last_activity_str:
            last_activity = datetime.fromisoformat(last_activity_str)
        else:
            last_activity = tz.now()
        session_timeout = tz.timedelta(seconds=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
        email_confirmed = False
        if tz.now() - last_activity > session_timeout:
            User = get_user_model()
            users = User.objects.filter(email=request.session.get('email', ''))
            if users.exists():
                user = users.first()
                user.delete()
            # Если прошло более 5 минут, считаем сессию подтвержденной фиктивно
            email_confirmed = True
        # Обновляем состояние сессии
        request.session['email_confirmed'] = email_confirmed
        request.session.save()
        # Возвращаем JsonResponse без 'last_activity'
        return JsonResponse({'email_confirmed': email_confirmed})
    
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.session.get('email', ''))
            if not user.email_confirmed:
                user.delete()
                # Удаляем email_confirmed из сессии и обновляем сессию
                del request.session['email_confirmed']
                request.session.modified = True
                return JsonResponse({'email_confirmed': False})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'email_confirmed': True})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'User does not exist.'})
```

check_session.js :

```
let checkSessionUrl;
var body = document.querySelector('body[data-url]');
let navbar = document.querySelector('nav[data-url]');

if (body) {
    checkSessionUrl = body.getAttribute('data-url');
} else if (navbar) {
    checkSessionUrl = navbar.getAttribute('data-url');
}

if (checkSessionUrl) {
    function checkSession() {
        fetch(checkSessionUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.email_confirmed === true) {
                   
                        window.location.href = "/";
                  
                    
                    
                }
            });
    }
    // Check the session every 1 minute 
    setInterval(checkSession, 60000);
}
```

timer.js :

```
let session_timeout;
let last_activ;
var body = document.querySelector('body');

if (body) {
    session_timeout = body.getAttribute('data-session-timeout');
    last_activ = body.getAttribute('data-last-activity');

    const sessionExpiryTime = session_timeout * 1000;
    console.log(session_timeout);
    console.log(sessionExpiryTime);
    const warningTime = 30 * 1000;
    const lastActivity = new Date(last_activ);
    console.log(lastActivity);
    const sessionExpiryDate = new Date(lastActivity.getTime() + sessionExpiryTime);

    function checkSession() {
        const timeLeft = sessionExpiryDate - new Date();

        // Найдите div с помощью его id
        const warningDiv = document.getElementById('insert_timer');

        if (warningDiv) {
            // Установите его содержимое только если элемент найден
            if (timeLeft <= warningTime) {
                warningDiv.textContent = 'Ваша сессия истекает через ' + Math.round(timeLeft / 1000) + ' секунд';
            }

                 
        }
    }

    setInterval(checkSession, 1000);
}
```